# how to get reusable API ID in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a case where I have to send the ID parameter to another page, and on another page I have to receive the ID that was sent on the first page.
on the first page I have API data in the form of a list and each card/data has a different ID, when the user chooses card A then what is sent is ID A and on another page must receive ID A, if the user chooses card B then what is sent is ID B and on other pages must accept ID B

i have two API

> first the API data is a list and I want to send this ID.

[image]

> and this is the second API where when accessing this API an ID must be sent.

[image]

how do i make the ID reusable without having to type it in the API because this code is hardcore code how do i make it so that when the user selects another card it automatically displays a different ID based on the user's choice.

I'm confused here

> page one

[image]

> page two detail (get ID in page one)

[image]

```
Future<ModelAbsensi> getDetailAbs() async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/absensi_perkuliahan?id_kelas_kuliah=c92f49f7-cabf-423a-bfa5-ae798a3048d9',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );
    print('${response.statusCode}');
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      Data detailKurikulum = Data.fromJson(result);
      ModelAbsensi? l = detailKurikulum.mataKuliah as ModelAbsensi?;
      return l!;
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

button click

```
SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 38,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: ((context) {
                        return DetailAbsensi(
                          jadwal: post,
                        );
                      }),
                      settings: RouteSettings(
                        arguments: todos,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xffC9F7F5),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Absensi",
                  style: bold5.copyWith(
                    color: const Color(
                      0xff1BC5BD,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question, please simplify it more

Comment: You need to know how you can pass variables between widgets? If this is what you want, provide me with the navigation code (when you click on button)

Comment: When you navigate to the detail screen, just pass the id to it, then get it from the detail screen. I assume `getDetailAbs()` is run in the detail screen so you can maybe use a `getDetailAbs(String id)` then in `Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/absensi_perkuliahan?id_kelas_kuliah=$id',
      ),`
replace the hardcoded id with `$id`

Comment: @AnasSafi I've updated add button

Comment: @Alan Chan I've tried but to no avail and confused

Comment: @AlanChan https://drive.google.com/file/d/18O-ZR7SlBVp87Hde_JBMkdEp-m092GRf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you sure `post` here `jadwal: post` present data object which you need to pass it to `DetailAbsensi` class?

Comment: can you provide `Jadwal Kuliah` and `Absensi Perkuliahan` snippet code? 
you can pass the id as param to next Screen

Comment: @AnasSafi post data in CARD

Comment: @pmatatias >Jadwal Kuliah https://pastebin.com/3qCfSi1W >Absensi Perkuliahan https://pastebin.com/JgtQJmyw Card https://pastebin.com/A0Ui2FKr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this exmaple:

you can run it on  : [https://dartpad.dev/](https://dartpad.dev/?id)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const AScreen());
  }
}

class AScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AScreen> createState() => _AScreenState();
}

class _AScreenState extends State<AScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Screen A"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("card $index"),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => BScreen(id: "card $index"),
                          ));
                    },
                    child: const Text("Go to B"))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<String> getData(String id) async {
  return Future.value("test abc with ID:   $id");
}

class BScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BScreen({Key? key, this.id = ''}) : super(key: key);
  final String id;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("B Screen")),
      body: Center(child:FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(id),
        builder: (context, snapshot) => Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(snapshot.data.toString()),
          ],
        ),
      ),)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cZlZfDtgeDrgRpE8fH1DSJ6IVfXOd6-S/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Check out how data can be passed from one page to another here
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

```
Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: ((context) {
                    return DetailAbsensi(
                      jadwal: post,
                    );
                  }),
                  settings: RouteSettings(
                    arguments: todos[index],//you have to specify index of list
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

[image]

Comment: i try it, but an error https://drive.google.com/file/d/14I4UDRUAjacsj_rbZyARXx46x_pC3ABs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where is your list in code?